# C# - When reference type is passed using the out keyword, then can calling function code control the outer object?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, out

In C#, I understand that when ref type is passed, by default it gets passed by value - the value is the address so any changes to the object attributes in inner function reflect on the outer object as well. However assigning inner object to null or another object or creating a new object (using new keyword) wont affect the outer object. To achieve the later we need to pass the reference type (object) by ref using the ref keyword.

This question is about the out keyword. When a value type is passed using the out keyword, the address gets passed to the calling function and any update reflects to the outer object as well.

However, when a reference type (say object of class Car) is passed using the out keyword, then can calling function code control the outer object?

```
function foo(out Car x)
{
  x=null //or x=new Car(); //or x.speed=0 
 //Will the last one (x.speed=0) reflect to outer object, where as the
 //1st 2 - that is - the null or new assignments wont reflect?)
}
Car c= new Car();
c.speed=100;
foo(out c);
console.writeline(x.speed);
```

Will outer object 'c' now point to the new object that was created in the function?

Or do we not have the concept of pass by ref with the out keyword?

Comment: _`x.speed=0`_ will give you a compile error.

Comment: Also, I think you should avoid both ref and out in C# code. There are better solutions.

Answer (score 4):

`out` is really the same as `ref`, under the hood. So it works the same way, with a few cosmetic differences:

- You can pass an uninitialized variable in an `out` parameter (in a `ref` parameter you must pass an initialized variable)
- Inside the function, the variable is first treated as uninitialized, so you must first assign it a value before doing something like `c.speed=0`;
- Before returning from the function you **MUST** assign a value to the variable
- After returning from the function, the variable is treated as initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Ref is used to pass a reference to a variable, so you can change it. Out is used only to return a value, it doesn't care about the object you pass on and it will cause compile errors if you have execution branches that don't set the value inside your method or use the value before you set it.

So in your case, instantiating c does nothing. The result is null and you will get a runtime exception when trying to access .speed (which I assume is from c, not x)

Code with out:

```
Car c;
foo(out c); //if foo doesn't set c, you get compile errors
// now c is set by foo
```

Code with ref:

```
Car c=new Car();
foo(ref c);
// c was perhaps modified or set by foo
```

Code with ref that won't compile:

```
Car c;
foo(ref c); //error because c is not instantiated
```

Code with out that won't compile:

```
static void foo(out string text) {
  DoSomethingWith(text); //error because text is not instantiated
  text="something";
}
```

Comment: "Ref is used to pass a reference to an object" - no, it's used to pass a reference to a *variable*. If you just use a value parameter with a reference type, the value of that parameter is "a reference to an object". It would be nice if we had entirely orthogonal terminology for these different things (a reference as a value, vs a pass-by-reference parameter) but while we don't, we need to be very careful.

Comment: I agree. I used "object" because you can cast anything as one. I've changed the text.